# Call SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure from PHP passing in Parameters

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to call a sql server stored procedure from PHP passing in some parameters. 
I have the following:

```
$serverName = "DB";
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>"***", "PWD"=>"***", "Database"=>"database");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$tsl = "EXEC GetAccountUser(?, ?)";
```

However when I pass in an array of params, it does not work.

Can someone please help? Example code would be appreciated.

Comment: Example code would be appreciated.

Comment: I also have had a hard time sending parameters to SQL Server stored procedures, has anyoe fond anygood examles that works?

Answer (score 0):

```
$addProduct = $obj->ExecuteQuery("Begin;DECLARE @ProductCode as varchar (100) ;EXEC CREATEPRODUCT'$pname', '$price', @ProductCode OUTPUT, '$merchantId';select @ProductCode;End;");

$productCode = $addProduct[0][0];
```

For more explanation, you can visit [this site](http://developer99.blogspot.com/2011/07/calling-ms-sql-sp-from-php.html).